# Unable to load React or Redux Chrome extensions on Electron 10

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, electron, redux-devtools

It looks like Electron 10 doesn't work with React and Redux DevTools Chrome extensions. When loading Redux extension, I'm getting the following error.

```
(node:17777) ExtensionLoadWarning: Warnings loading extension at /home/perttu/.config/Electron/extensions/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd: Unrecognized manifest key 'commands'. Unrecognized manifest key 'homepage_url'. Unrecognized manifest key 'page_action'. Unrecognized manifest key 'short_name'. Unrecognized manifest key 'update_url'. Permission 'notifications' is unknown or URL pattern is malformed. Permission 'contextMenus' is unknown or URL pattern is malformed. Permission 'tabs' is unknown or URL pattern is malformed. Cannot load extension with file or directory name _metadata. Filenames starting with "_" are reserved for use by the system. 
Error: Exited with code 9
```

The same kind of errors occurs when loading React Developer Tools.

```
(node:19201) ExtensionLoadWarning: Warnings loading extension at /home/perttu/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/4.8.2_0: Unrecognized manifest key 'browser_action'. Unrecognized manifest key 'minimum_chrome_version'. Unrecognized manifest key 'update_url'. Manifest contains a differential_fingerprint key that will be overridden on extension update. Cannot load extension with file or directory name _metadata. Filenames starting with "_" are reserved for use by the system.
```

I suspect that the problem is in the Electron itself, because although Redux tab is visible in the UI, the window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ is not defined. Redux tab itself is complaining that *No store found. Make sure to follow the instructions.*

It's easy to reproduce the problem by cloning https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate and changing the Electron version to 10.

So, has somebody been successful in loading either React or Redux extensions on Electron 10?

Comment: This is a known issue with the latest versions of Electron: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/23662

There are a few workarounds listed that might help you out.

Comment: I tried those workarounds, but they didn't work (I'm running Linux, which may also affect the behavior).